# Using lapply and '[' function to select columns in a list of data frames

Tags: r, select, lapply

I have a list of 100 data frames (with 100 rows, 25 columns) resulting from the splitting of a big data frame (10000 rows, 25 columns)

For all my smaller data frames, I want to select 7 columns out of the 25. I use `lapply` with `'['` function :

```
Values_selected <- lapply(listdf, '[', c("Chemicals", "Begin.Date", "End.Date", "Less.Than", "Concentration", "Uncertainty.Value", "Measuring.Unit"))
```

The "Less. Than" columns has 2 possibilities : "<" and " " (empty). Therefore, I wish to obtain 2 new lists:

1 list of DF containing, for each data frame, all the rows that do contain "<" in Less.Than;

1 list of DF contaning, for each  data frame, all the rows that do not contain "<" in Less.Than

I've tried this :

```
Values_selected_AboveDL <- lapply(Values_selected, '[', ("Less.Than" == ""))
Values_selected_BelowDL <- lapply(Values_selected, '[', ("Less.Than" == "<"))
```

But I obtain very strange things. The list of list `Values_selected_AboveDL` has data frames with 100 rows but 0 column....
Something is wrong with my `lapply` or  `'['` function. How can I modify my query to select the only the rows in each data frame that contain (or not) "<" in the column Less.Than ?

These are my data :

```
List of 1496
 $ A110E.xxxx.CO2         :'data.frame':    13 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Chemicals         : Factor w/ 53 levels "","CO2","CO2",..: 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
  ..$ Begin.Date       : Factor w/ 368 levels "","2018-12-28",..: 4 32 60 88 116 144 172 199 227 255 ...
  ..$ End.Date         : Factor w/ 369 levels "","2018-12-29",..: 30 58 86 114 142 170 198 225 253 281 ...
  ..$ Less.Than        : Factor w/ 2 levels "","<": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ Concentration   : num [1:13] 0.00206 0.00276 0.00192 0.00362 0.00292 0.00174 0.0028 0.00245 0.00311 0.00278 ...
  ..$ Uncertainty.Value: num [1:13] 0.000537 0.000381 0.000508 0.000791 0.000675 0.00105 0.000375 0.000351 0.000532 0.000619 ...
  ..$ Measuring.Unit   : Factor w/ 7 levels "","Mol/G-C","Mol/KG",..: 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ A110E.xxxxx.CO      :'data.frame':   13 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Chemicals         : Factor w/ 53 levels "","CO","CO",..: 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 ...
  ..$ Begin.Date       : Factor w/ 368 levels "","2018-12-28",..: 4 32 60 88 116 144 172 199 227 255 ...
  ..$ End.Date         : Factor w/ 369 levels "","2018-12-29",..: 30 58 86 114 142 170 198 225 253 281 ...
  ..$ Less.Than        : Factor w/ 2 levels "","<": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..$ Concentration   : num [1:13] 6.07e-05 8.57e-05 6.03e-05 1.04e-04 5.74e-05 9.20e-05 3.59e-05 6.82e-05 4.22e-05 1.05e-04 ...
  ..$ Uncertainty.Value: num [1:13] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Measuring.Unit   : Factor w/ 7 levels "","Mol/G-C","Mol/KG",..: 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using anonymous function makes it clear I think :

```
Values_selected_AboveDL <- lapply(Values_selected, function(x) x[x$Less.Than == "", ])
#Or
#Values_selected_AboveDL <- lapply(Values_selected, function(x) x[x$Less.Than != "<", ])
Values_selected_BelowDL <- lapply(Values_selected, function(x) x[x$Less.Than == "<", ])
```

Without an anonymous function you can use `subset` :

```
Values_selected_AboveDL <- lapply(Values_selected, subset, Less.Than == "")
Values_selected_BelowDL <- lapply(Values_selected, subset Less.Than == "<")
```

---

Using a reproducible example with `mtcars` :

```
df <- mtcars
df$gear <- factor(df$gear)
Values_selected <- split(df, mtcars$cyl)
lapply(Values_selected, subset, gear == "3")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, if I use your first proposition, R returns me "Error in x[x$Less.Than == "<", ] : incorrect number of dimensions".  With your second proposition, R returns me "Error in subset.default(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Less.Than' not found". I tried "Less.Than" (with quotation marks), but then, I always get a list of empty data frames...

Comment: @Sylvain Can you add first few rows of data using `dput`?

Comment: Well, these are confidential data actually, but can you tell me what is your idea behind this ?

Comment: @Sylvain You don't have to share actual data you can generate a fake dataset which is similar to what you have. I have updated the answer using an example where this syntax works, please check.

Comment: I edit my question to show the first elements of Values_selected but I do not know whether it will be useful for you

Comment: I can't find a reason why this would not work. In the updated example `str(Values_selected)` is the same as yours where `gear` is a factor. You could try to convert the data into character and try again. `Values_selected[] <- lapply(Values_selected, function(x) {x$Less.Than <- as.character(x);x})`

Comment: Anyway, there is an issue even at the beginning with my initial big data frame (`df_2019`) because R returns me that Less.Than is not found when I try `df_2019_AboveDL <- lapply(df_2019, subset, Less.Than == "")
df_2019_BelowDL <- lapply(df_2019, subset, Less.Than == "<")`. Even more, this is also valuable for all my columns...

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct column name then. Anyway, I don't think I can debug this further without any reproducible example. As I have shown in my answer it works for `mtcars` dataset so syntax is not an issue here.